# React on repository function call in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've been looking for a way to do this for a while now, hopefully someone will know what the preferred way to do this is.

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data to create a REST app that will allow the user to create queries. When the query is created I would like to send a message out to a queue which will be picked up by a different app.

The approaches I have tried so far:

1. Create a listener and annotated the `@Entity` class with `@EntityListeners(FilterListener.class)`. This approach unfortunately did not work as Listeners cannot have any non static components injected.
2. Create a custom annotation to be used in the `Repository` which will override the `save`. This requires me to implement this method base method, not sure what I would need to call.

It seems that the best way would be to use the second approach and call super.save() on the implementation that is created by Spring Data. Is that doable?

Comment: can you provide the code you tried for option(1) ?

Comment: Do you only use Spring Data or also Spring Data REST?

Comment: @zeroflagL I'm using both

Comment: @javaguy I've managed to solve this by overriding save and calling em.persist on the passed object. I will post an answer this evening

Comment: Then you can use `@RepositoryEventHandler`.